# why is regex matching into string output of file.read() different when i assign it to a variable?

Tags: python, regex, file

i am trying to regex match into a yml file, and i have found a situation i don't understand with how read() works in Python.

i’m opening a <4k yaml file as such:
`with open(filename, 'r') as fptr:`

i have three things to compare wrt behavior:

1. ftpr.read()
2. new_file = fptr.read()
3. copied the stdout from fptr.read() into variable “filedummy”

if i apply type() around all three, i get 'str'
if i print each to stdout, they're identical

now if i apply regex:

```
print [match for match in re.findall(YAML_PATTERN, filedummy, flags=re.MULTILINE)], "<=== matches"
print [match for match in re.findall(YAML_PATTERN, new_file, flags=re.MULTILINE)], "<=== matches"
print [match for match in re.findall(YAML_PATTERN, fptr.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)], "<=== NOTHING"
```

note: this behavior still occurs if i do these actions in isolation, so it doesn't seem to be because i'm exhausting the ftpr.read() output

Comment: You do realize that `fptr.read()` will only read the file and return the contents once? After reading the file, you either need to rewind it with `fptr.seek(offset, from_what)` to read it again...

Comment: @dawg - yes, i realize that. that's why i wrote the note stating that this happens in isolation, meaning that it's not because i haven't rewound the file. but this is a very going point.

Comment: It's impossible to have different outcomes from `new_file` and direct `fptr.read()` expression. You need to provide more context, i.e. a minimal example.